# Retrieve grouped relation with Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent, group-by, eloquent-relationship

I have a relationship which looks like this:

```
User
 - id
```

```
Menu
 - id
 - appetizer_id
 - main_course_id
 - dessert_id
```

```
User_Menu
 - user_id
 - menu_id
```

and corresponding models:

```php
class User
{
    public function menus()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Menu', 'user_menu', 'user_id', 'menu_id');
    }
}

class Menu 
{
    public function dessert()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Dessert', 'dessert_id');
    }
}
```

In other words there are users and menus with a many to many relationship. Now I would like to retrieve all the distinct *desserts* for a given user. I've tried using group by, but it does not allow me to select and group by a single column, because the pivot columns are always included in the query:

```php
$desserts = User::find(1)->menus()
    ->select('dessert_id')
    ->groupBy('dessert_id')
    ->with('dessert')
    ->get();
```

throws the following error:

```
'User_Menu.user_id' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Comment: will the user be authenticated user??

Comment: @dqureshiumar Yes, although it shouldn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$desserts = User::join('User_Menu', 'User.id', '=', 'User_Menu.user_id')
                ->join('Menu', 'User_Menu.menu_id', '=','Menu.id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the primary key on Menu, it's just another id field. But I was wondering if there's a way doing this using the "belongsToMany" relationship on the User model referencing the Menu model, I called it "menus" in my example

Comment: Yes there is.  Please update your code.. I'll help you with the solution

Comment: Great, I've added my model definitions